# Getting the last record in SQL in WHERE condition and Group by

Tags: group-by

I have similar situation of Getting the last record in SQL in WHERE condition
 examples of table

TESTING
with fields of 
SubjectName
TestType
TestDate
ResultIs
Want to return Positive test record if one TestType for that TestDate is Positive, Likewise
want to return Negative test record if all TestTypes for that TestDate are Negative.

I CAN LIVE WITHOUT RETURNING THE Positive results if the code is easier to write without returning records that have any test for that date as positive, because that could be a separate view for a different crystal report "positive.rpt"

So if I need 1 record per date when there are no positive tests, (same as saying I need 1 record per date when all tests are negative)

TESTING (which is really a view).

```
    SubjectName TestDate ResultIs TestType
    =========== ======== ======== ========
    Alexandaria 20140215 Negative test0001
    Alexandaria 20140215 Positive test0002
    Alexandaria 20140215 Positive test0003
    Alexandaria 20140220 Negative test0002
    Alexandaria 20140220 Negative test0003
    Alexandaria 20140228 Negative test0003
    Alexandaria 20140228 Positive test0004
    Alexandaria 20140228 Positive test0005
```

TestType does not matter in the selection,  a group by of the first 3 would be perfect, but only when all records for a date are negative. choosing the last record for a date with the ResultIS sinking to the bottom (or Max). Do I need to do a subqquery?

Preferred output of query into a view of this form
 view

```
    SubjectName TestDate ResultIs TestType
    =========== ======== ======== ========
    Alexandaria 20140215 Positive test0002
    Alexandaria 20140215 Positive test0003
    Alexandaria 20140220 Negative test0003 or test0002 does not matter
    Alexandaria 20140228 Positive test0004
    Alexandaria 20140228 Positive test0005
```

or just only negative records with no positive for that date.

```
    SubjectName TestDate ResultIs TestType
    =========== ======== ======== ========
    Alexandaria 20140220 Negative test0003 or test0002 does not matter
```

furthermore since this last output view that is defined as negative only records for a date, i dont even need the testtype or the Result output, just name, and date
But using a where clause of "negative" would still somehow include dates with Positive results. i dont know a way around that.

```
    SubjectName TestDate 
    =========== ========
    Alexandaria 20140220
```

Feb 20th is the only negative only date, that is what I would settle for.

DEMOTABLE IS THE LIST OF SUBJECTNAMES

```
    Alexandria
    Betty
    Tom
    Sue
```

SELECT SubjectName,TestDate FROM TESTING
inner join Testing to Demotable (if subjectname=subjectname)
where resultIS=Negative
group by subjectName,TestDate

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I don't know what that is

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server@2012Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      11.0.3000.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      11.0.3000.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.0.8112.16421
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.18408
Operating System      6.1.7601